# How can i implement react native p2p live chat in my app?

Tags: react-native, chat, hybrid-mobile-app

Please I'm building an app with react native cli and I need to integrate a p2p live chat in it. Is there any simple SDK out there to use with proper documentation. A lot of them out there are so vague in explaining how to use them.

Please help. Thanks